# How does Haskell pick a type for an ambiguous expression

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

If an expression can be typed in several ways, how does Haskell pick which one to use?

**Motivating example**

Take this example:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Data.Ratio (Ratio)
Prelude Data.Ratio> f z s = show $ truncate $ z + (read s)
Prelude Data.Ratio> :type f
f :: (RealFrac a, Read a) => a -> String -> String
Prelude Data.Ratio> s = take 30 (cycle "12345")
Prelude Data.Ratio> s
"123451234512345123451234512345"
Prelude Data.Ratio> f 0 s
"123451234512345121227855101952"
Prelude Data.Ratio> f (0::Double) s
"123451234512345121227855101952"
Prelude Data.Ratio> f (0::Float) s
"123451235679745417161721511936"
Prelude Data.Ratio> f (0::Ratio Integer) (s ++ "%1")
"123451234512345123451234512345"
Prelude Data.Ratio> show $ truncate $ read s
"123451234512345121227855101952"
```

When I used `0` without any type, I got the same result as for `(0::Double)`. So it *seems* to me that when I just invoke `f 0 s`, it uses a version of `read` that produces a `Double`, and a version of `truncate` that turns that `Double` into some integral type. I introduces the variable `z` so I could have some easy control over the type here. With that I could show that other interpretations are possible, e.g. using `Float` or exact ratios. So why `Double`? The last line, which omits the addition, shows that the behavior is independent of that zero constant.

I guess something tells Haskell that `Double` is a more canonical type than others, either in general or when used as a `RealFrac`, so if it can interpret an expression using `Double` as an intermediate result, but also some other types, then it will prefer the `Double` interpretation.

**Core questions**

- Is my interpretation observed behavior correct, and there is an implicit type default here?
- What is the name for this kind of preference?
- Is there a way to disable such a choice of canonical type and enforce explicit type specifications for things that can be interpreted in multiple ways?

**Own research**

I've read that https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_basics_II#Polymorphic_guesswork writes

> With no other restrictions, 5.12 will assume the default Fractional type of Double, so (-7) will become a Double as well.

That appears to confirm my assumption that `Double` is somehow blessed as the default type for some parent category of `RealFrac`. It still doesn't offer a name for that concept, nor a complete list of the rules around that.

**Background**

The situation I actually want to handle is more like this:

```
f :: Integer -> String -> Integer
f scale str = truncate $ (fromInteger scale) * (read str)
```

So I want a function that takes a string, reads it as a decimal fraction, multiplies it with a given number, then truncates the result back to an integer. I was very surprised to find that this compiles without me specifying the intermediate fractional type anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is an ambiguous type variable `v` with a `Num v` constraint, it gets defaulted to `Integer` or `Double`, tried in that order, whichever satisfies all other constraints on `v`.

Those defaulting rules are explained in the Haskell Report: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-620004

The GHC manual also explains additional defaulting rules in GHCi (this means trying things in GHCi will not give you an accurate picture of what is going on when you compile a program): https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci

Comment: ...and you can change what types get tried in what order (but not the rules that define when to try) with a `default` declaration.